# Given the 2D velocity field $v_x = -2y$, $v_y = 2x$ find the path line equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the 2D velocity field $v_x = -2y$, $\, v_y = 2x$ find the path line equations. The book said the path lines are circles, i.e. $x^2 + y^2 = \text{constant} = X^2 + Y^2$. Where

\begin{cases} 
x = x(X,Y,t) \\ y = y(X,Y,t) \\ X = x(X,Y,t_0) \\Y = y(X,Y,t_0)
\end{cases}

I'm approaching it like this
\begin{align}    
v_x &= \frac{dx}{dt} = -2y \\ \\
v_x &= \frac{d\left[ x(X,Y,t) \right]}{dt} = -2\left[ y(X,Y,t) \right] \\ \\
\int_{t_0}^{t} &\frac{dx}{dt} dt = -2 \int_{t_0}^{t} y \, dt \\ \\
x(&X,Y,t) - x(X,Y,t_0) = -2\int_{t_0}^{t} y \, dt \\ \\
x - &X = -2\int_{t_0}^{t} y \, dt 
\end{align}

A similar equation can be made for $y$ and $Y$. But this is where I hit a wall. I'm thinking there's a much simpler way to do this.

Comment: Do you know matrix exponential and its use to solve differential equations?

Comment: I've seen it performed in lecture (different course from a while ago) but wouldn't know how to apply it here.

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2x$$
Divide the first equation by the second 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}$$
Integrate to give $x^{2}+y^{2}=c$